# Show an icon for a echo esc_html value

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

On my website I have a list of members and for each of them I display some info. One is the email address.
I would like to show the email address as an icon rather than the actual email address.
The email is dynamically populated by the

```
<?php
    $email_address = $user->user_email;
    if ( ! empty( $email_address ) ) {
        ?>
<div><span class="label">Email address</span><br> <?php echo esc_html( $email_address ); ?></div>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```

How can I add the icon here? I will remove the label as well and just show the icon.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A standard image tag should work. Here's how to add with PHP (untested):

```php
$email_address = $user->user_email;

if ( ! empty( $email_address ) && is_email( $email_address ) ) {
    $email_icon_src = ''; // Add the URL to your icon here

    printf( 
        '<div><a href="%s"><img src="%s" /></a></div>', 
        esc_url( 'mailto:' . $email_address ), 
        esc_url( $email_icon_src ) 
    );
}
```